# Add REST API Client in Visual Studio Default Option

Tags: api, rest, client, autorest

For the last year I have been working on the same project that uses the rest api client generated by "// Code generated by Microsoft (R) AutoRest Code Generator 0.16.0.0"

I use to follow the same procedure in order to regenerate it.
I right clicked the project and have chosen the option "Add Rest API Client"
[add rest api client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa0Ik.png)

After I clicked the option this was the default option I could see

[Old UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaccG.jpg)

I recently updated my Visual Studio and when I click the same option this is the UI it returns back
[new UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWetW.png)

It seems like that ADD Rest Api client just goes to add service reference menu instead, also it is giving me option to regenerate the api using Nswag tool which I dont really want. I repaired my VS, reinstalled and double checked all extensions, I just dont understand where is the old menu. Anybody experienced this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this new UI comes with a new Visual Studio Update. In case you want to regenerate it using the old tool you have to use Visual Studio 2017(it still works there) or you have to do it manually with auto-rest.

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same issue and had to use old version autorest to create the api client.

```
npm install -g autorest@3.0.6247
```

Create .cmd file and run it in the solution folder:

```
autorest ^
--csharp ^
--modeler=Swagger ^
--input-file=http://localhost:8080/MyRestApi/swagger/docs/v1 ^
--namespace=<YourNameSpace> ^
--override-client-name=<MyRestApiClientName> ^
--output-folder=<absolute path>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also stumbling upon that problem. We rely heavily on Autorest (both from command line and the "old" Visual Studio generated code). So after some digging in the different Autorest modules i found that you can add a --legacy flag on the new autorest (v3) client, and get the old behavior/generated code from Autorest V2 and Visual Studio 2019 prior to the convertion to NSwag generated code.

Link to Autorest documentation: https://github.com/Azure/autorest.csharp